# Website down after doing a domain transfer

Tags: dns, domain-transfer, icann

We have a domain which was hosted with a provider. We asked for a domain transfer, using the AUTH CODE, from our new provider.

Now the situation is that the site is down, because the DNS do not point to any server.

We asked our old provider, and they don't see the domain and cannot give any advice except waiting!

We don't have access to any control panel from the old provider point, and in the new cp the domain appears as "transfer pending", so we are completely lost.

To make the nightmare worst, the technical and administrative emails were those of the domain so we cannot check if there are any errors or further instructions.

So what can we do? Ask for help to ICANN? We have made dozens of domains transfers without pointing to new DNS first, and never found any problems before.

Comment: For domain transfer I don't think you should have website or point your DNS to server. it is just simplest process. Get the auth code from OLD provider, give that auth code to new provider and they will release your domain within a few weeks. It is standard process. I just doubt your new DNS provider, may be they don't know much about DNS transfer process(May be their main business is hosting), because they can advice you to take some legal(that is why you pay extra money on ICANN) action if some DNS provider don't release your domain.

Comment: They could have release our domain (we trust it is that way), but somehow they have deleted all content in the host or, at least, deleted the DNS, as now they don't point to anything. We may contact ICANN, because our client is losing money without its e-commerce. The OLD provider did not caution about any effect that the domain transfer could cause, and they assure they have not changed anything, and they haven't got any Control Panel. It is the first time in my life that I see a hosting company (the client purchased the domain through them) which does not have a Control Panel of some kind.

Comment: You do not give enough data to help you, such as the domain name involved. But in short, especially in gTLDs, a domain name transfer does not change the nameservers so it can not be by itself the cause of all your problems. Of course as soon as the domain arrives at the new registrar, it can change the  nameservers if you instructed it to do so. As you have unfortunately discovered using the domain name itself in email addresses of contacts of the domain is a bad idea.